# Filter on my module for Prestashop 1.6

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create a custom list for my module on Prestashop 1.6 and I need to get data from three different tables. My problem is the `$this->_filter` variable, how can I do that?

I need to do this:

```
$query = '
SELECT s.*, pl.*
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'`scd_gift` s
INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl
ON s.id_product = pl.id_product 
WHERE s.`id_gift_type` = '.(int)$id_gift_type.' and id_lang='.$id_lang;
```

Here is my function:

```
public function getCustomListHostessGifts() {
    $this->table = 'scd_gift';
    $this->list_id = 'hostess_gift';
    $this->lang = true;
    $this->identifier = 'id_scd_gift';
    $this->_orderBy = 'id_product';
    $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';

    $this->addRowAction('delete');

    $this->fields_list = (array(
        'id_product' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'class' => 'fixed-width-xs', 
                              'align' => 'center'),
        'name' => array('title' => $this->l('Name'), 'filter_key' => 'b!name'),
    ));

    $this->clearFilters();

    $hostessType = MlmGiftsModule::getGiftTypeIdByGiftTypeName('_HOSTESSGIFT_');

    $this->_join = Shop::addSqlAssociation('scd_gift', 'a');

    $this->_filter = ' 
        INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl
                ON s.id_product = pl.id_product 
                AND a.`id_gift_type` ='.$hostessType ;

    $this->toolbar_title = $this->l('Hostess gifts:');

    return $this->renderList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_filter` is use to set filter parameters passed in backoffice list search fields.
Any `JOIN` sentence must be set in `_join` var:

```
$this->_join = Shop::addSqlAssociation('scd_gift', 'a');
       . ' INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl
                ON s.id_product = pl.id_product 
                AND a.`id_gift_type` ='.$hostessType ;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

PixelWeb's answer is correct, but of course, there is no semicolon after

```
$this->_join = Shop::addSqlAssociation('scd_gift', 'a')
```

Additional. You may skip this line anyway, because Prestashop adds the default SQL association "a" for the table in the controller itsself.